# Remove items from list by comparing items from other List

Tags: java, java-stream

Hello I am trying to remove items from a list by checking other list.It looks something like this ,

```
List<Model> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Model("pink",4),new Model("red",3))
List<Model> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Model("pink",4),new Model("pink",3),new Model("violet",9))
```

I want to remove both pink items from list2 as the same contains in list1,therefore I cannot use equals as I am comparing only using color.

How to do it in a good way ,maybe using streams ?

The final result should look like :

```
[Model("violet",9)]
```

Comment: Add the desired result to your question.

Comment: Is there some way for you to access the model's color? I.e., can you do `Model.color` or `Model.getColor()`?

Comment: done, edited the post to show desired result.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 ofcourse, all attributes has getter setter

Comment: Does the second parameter of Model constructor (quantity ?) play any role in your logic?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `list2` is mutable you can simply use `removeIf`

```
list2.removeIf(model->list1.stream().anyMatch(m->m.getColor().equals(model.getColor())));
```

If `list2` is immutable then you can use `filter` and collect the output into another list

```
List<Model> result = list2.stream()
                          .filter(model->list1.stream()
                                              .noneMatch(m->m.getColor().equals(m.getColor())))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is wring : conditions should be                          m->m.getColor().equals(model.getColor()

Answer (score 2):

Trivially, the answer to your question is: **impossible** - you can't remove anything from a List obtained by invoking `Arrays.asList` (you can `.set`, but you can't add, remove, or in any other way change the size; it's just a light wrapper around an array and arrays are fixed size in java). So let's assume you have 2 ArrayList instances, possibly created with `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(...))`, then you can remove things.

The data structure you've chosen is inefficient. The 'best' way, if constrained by 'I have 2 lists', is to just... take it one step at a time:

```
Set<String> forbiddenColors = list1.stream()
  .map(Model::getColor)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
list2.removeIf(x -> forbiddenColors.contains(x.getColor()));
```

By using list, the speed of this should be ~O(n), vs. O(n^2). It's not going to matter unless you have many thousands of things in these lists, but just in case you do - this won't perform badly.